# How can save input type in database?

Tags: php, jquery

Suppose I have a setting page, which contains different information about a person. In that page, it contains a section for Hobbies. And the person can add as many hobbies he wants. There should be an add button to add more fields for hobbies.

Adding more fields dynamically is an easy task using jquery. But what I want is that when a user adds a field dynamically, then that field should be saved to the database, I mean to say that, usually, when we create a field using jquery, it disappears on page refresh. But I want to list the information as it is. (within the field). How can I save input types that are created dynamically?

I have done a lot of research, I have not recieved a single help. I am expecting Stackoverflow team will surely help in this. My code for adding dynamic fields is as follow:

```
<div class="items">


    <div class="form-group"><label>Author Email:</label>
        <input id="author_email" class="form-control" name="author" required="required" type="EMAIL" />
    </div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add Field</button>
```

And Jquery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $("#items"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count

$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
    x++; //text box increment
    $(wrapper).append('

    <div class="form-group"><label for="title">Author Email:</label>' +
        '<input class="form-control col-md-11" id="author_email" type="email" placeholder=""name="author"/>' +
        '<a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-times"></a>
    </div>

    '); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove field
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Once again I want to confirm my question, I want to see hobbies in text fields even on page refresh.That is I also want to save the input types. What can I do for this. Should I add `<input type="text" name="hobby[]">` to database or something is better than this?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: What Jay said, but in addition, you are asking about a lot more than jQuery.  I do see you tagged PHP as your server side language, but you also need to post what you have done as far as storing this data into a database.  Right now, we have  no idea what your database relational language might be.

Comment: It is easy to downvote a question. But if you go through my question,I have mentioned that I am confused whether I should try adding field like <input type="text">.

Comment: use php to process the form and jquery to do error checks.

Comment: do you have any php to post if so please do so so we can find a solution

Comment: I want to ask that what is best way to save an input type in database?

Comment: Using prepared statements is the best way to save user input into a db.

Comment: Do you understand my question as I doubt I have clearly expressed my question. My question is not about saving a value rather than saving a text field

Comment: I believe you guys are understanding that I want to save a value like "text" or "something". But that is not my question.

Comment: Please rephrase this: "_then a user adds a **field** dynamically, then that **field** should be saved to the database_". And this: "How can I save input types that are created dynamically?". Because the 2nd paragraph is unclear; we don't know if you want to save just the input values, or the input types + input values.

Answer (score 0):

Your users aren't going to LITERALLY add fields from a database perspective, so you have to give them a data structure that supports it.

Here's an example of one such structure.  There's a million ways to do it.

Table - USER_DATA_TYPES

- DATA_TYPE_ID - PK
- DATA_TYPE_NAME
- This is not editable.  ID might be numeric, 2 string, 3 date.

Table - USER_FIELD_TYPES - Types of Fields that the user Adds

- USER_ID - (Data type depends on how you uniquely identify a user in the system) - PART OF PK
- FIELD_ID - Under the hood ID that gets generated.  NUMERIC.  Part of PK.
- FIELD_NAME - Name of the Field
- DATA_TYPE_ID - FK pointing to USER_DATA_TYPES
- ISMULTI - NUMBER of 1 or 0, to say whether its a multi-field

Table - USER_FIELD_DATA - The actual data for the user.  If ISMULTI=0, then you will at most have one record for the USER_ID/FIELD_ID combination.

- USER_ID - PART OF PK
- FIELD_ID - PART OF KEY
- FIELD_DATA_ID - PART OF KEY - Auto Generated
- DATA_VALUE (Make this a string - but there's an alternative way to do this)

A couple thoughts, you COULD put the USER_FIELD_DATA into 3 separate tables (one for numbers, one for strings, one for dates), or keep it in one table.  There's pros and cons to each way.  Obviously a pro of a single table is structural simplicity, but the con is filtering/sorting on the data that's numeric/date would require casting beforehand and also would require more space to store data.

Another thought that you might want to add columns to track the last change date, last change user to the data, in addition to a lot of other possible things you could try.